# How to display something determined by if the user is connected or not to a website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm looking for something that display some links (login & register) if (!userConnected) but if(userConnected) I want to display another informations than login & register.

I will display the elements by changing the states of userConnected bymyself so it doesn't have to be automatic, just functionnal if I put false to userConnected. Thanks!

I'm using React and react-router-dom in 5.2.0

`<Route exact path="/"> {userConnected ? <Home/> : <Register>} </Route>`

I've tried this but this is with new pages and me I want to be in the same page. So I thought to do the same home page twice and if the user is connected it will display the home page with her profile pic and if he's not login it will still display the home page but without profile pic and with the login and register links.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code? Are there any issues, errors? Can you clarify what "connected or not to a website" means exactly?

Comment: I'm thinking about the double home page that are exactly the same but without the things specified. But I think this is a bad method to do it properly so I'm looking for another way "cleaner".

Comment: What double home page?

Comment: I want to display exactly the same contents but with a little things different if the user is connected or not. So I copy the page that we have when user is connected and I change some little things and the user that aren't connected will see this homepage version ( the no connected version). But it require to do the same exact page 2 times only to change really little things in it. Sorry for my bad explanations

Comment: Pretend I'm your grandmother and I need to have explained every explicit detail. If you are just wanting to show variations of your home page then why not pass `userConnected` in as a prop and handle the variations in the component?

Comment: That's what I needed ! Thanks !